# Parsing insert queries from SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am exporting data from SQL server to an SQL file. The problem is some of the column entries that are strings contain commas so when I try to parse the SQL file (basically using string split with comma delim) I am not getting what I want. Anyone have a solution to this problem or a better idea?

Basically I need to separate the values in the query:

Example:

... VALUES (123, 'bob likes to eat berries, and beans')

If I split that using a comma as a delimiter I get:

```
123
'bob likes to eat berries
and beans'
```

Comment: Can you include the source code for the function which is splitting up the SQL file data? Without the exact code it might be hard to provide a valid answer.

Comment: The quick answer is to not use commas as a delimiter.  However, the real answer is going to depend on how exactly you are constructing that statement.  It really seems like a trivial thing to convert a row of data into inserts..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to export using a different delimiter.  What are you using to export?  If it's the [BCP command line utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), you could switch delimiters using the -t switch.  For example, `-t |` for pipe-delimited.

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks! I also used -r **\t** to help with the problem described in my reply to Chriseyre above.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried exporting as Tab seperated variables?

Comment: If I just export a csv or tab seperated (save results as deal) file I get some funkyness. Instead of each record being on it's own separate line I get some of the larger column entries broken up on separate lines.

Comment: @ryoung Are you using BCP (or the wizard in ssms which is basically a GUI for BCP)?  I always use tabs (which I believe is what it uses by default if you just don't specify a delimeter... but if you try to actually specify a tab it doesn't work right I don't think) and I've never had that problem.  Maybe your data is longer than mine though...

Comment: For creating a csv or tab delim file I just right click on the results from the query and select "Save Results As".

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained to using a comma as a delimiter? You could use a different character or series of characters you do not expect to show up in the strings.

Alternatively, depending on the data set, you could "encode" the strings in a temporary table and swap commas for a special character that you can identify later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression.

```
var myMatches = Regex.Matches(lineInFile, "(?:[^',]+)|(?:'[^']+')");
foreach(var m in myMatches)
{
   /* write m.ToString() to StringBuilder or file */
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the current format, you could you a regex like

```
((\d+), ('.*'))
```

to split it. The regex is not the best, but works with you exampe.